# switched view exited and try to enter again fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, modalviewcontroller

i have a problem in my app. in an tabbarcontroller i have a login view where i can enter a website. if the login data is correct the view switches to another view. works fine.

now my problem is, when i switch the tab and enter the login view tag again and try to login again, the view does not load.

Whats here the problem? should i dismissmodalviewcontroller when the view is unload or something else???

thanks for help,
brush51

EDIT1:
hi robin, in my login view is an button which calls a webview whit this code:

```
ShopWebViewController *shopWVC = [[ShopWebViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"ShopWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    shopWVC = [[ShopWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShopWebViewController" bundle:nil];
shopWVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[logView  presentModalViewController:shopWVC animated:YES];
```

And now when i exit the tabbar item where this logview is and enter it again, then the first view appears and the login/presentmodalviewcontroller doesnt work again.
cause of this i think that i may have to dismissmodalviewcontroller but dont know if this is right or not.

Comment: You might want to somewhat more precise and include some sample code of the creation of your view. Also, why would you want to call dismissModalViewController? Is the login view presented modally?

Comment: hi robin, i have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the login button:

```
ShopWebViewController *shopWVC = [[ShopWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShopWebViewController" bundle:nil];
shopWVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:shopWVC animated:YES];
[shopWVC release];
```

Then in your view controller that has just been presented modally, somewhere in your code (perhaps when login is successful?) you need to dismiss it with

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Rog for your answer. Where should i do that. i dont know that, because my ShopWebViewController is in a Tab Bar View. When i jump to another tab bar item how can i dismiss? is there a method like nibUnload/viewunload or something else which i can use??

Comment: I don't get why you need to dismiss it when the user jumps to another tab bar? The main idea of using a tab bar is that you get views that are pretty much independent from each other in the sense that I could be jumping from one to another and back, and continue to do exactly what I was doing so for instance if I am login into a view in one of the tab bars, and then tap another tab bar, I should be able to go back to the previous one to continue the login process.